# How to traverse through result set saved in a variable in xslt

Tags: xslt

```html
<xsl:variable name="result">
<values>
<value>1</value>
<value>1</value>
<value>1</value>
<value>1</value>
</values>
<xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="$result/values/value">
<xsl:copy-of select=".">
</xsl:for-each>
```

When i try to traverse with result set in for each loop its throwing error in eclipse javax parser but its working fine online xslt tools. How to make it work in eclipse also.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Eclipse uses Xalan (XSLT 1.0) and during online testing you used another XSLT engine and maybe XSLT 2.0.

Make the following changes:

- In the `stylesheet` tag add `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`
  and `extension-element-prefixes="exsl"` (it will be used below).
- Change your `for-each` instruction to
  `<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($result)/values/value">`.

I tested these changes on *xslttransform* with *Xalan* engine and it works
(on *Saxon 9...* engine it doesn't work, as "newer" Saxon versions do not
support `exsl`).

You have also to tidy up your source XML:

- Change `<xsl:variable>` to `</xsl:variable>` (it is a **closing** tag).
- Change `<xsl:copy-of select=".">` to `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`
  (add missing "/" at the end).

To build up your knowledge, read about `node-set` function.
Sometimes it is needed in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then there is nothing stopping you moving forward to XSLT 2.0. Install Saxon, and the problem will go away. XSLT 1.0 is 17 years old and was superseded over 10 years ago. There are some environments where you still have no choice, but in the Java world, it's time you moved forward.